# How are similar-fields that are optionally written, distinguished by flatbuffer reader?

Tags: protocol-buffers, optional-arguments, flatbuffers

Flatbuffer [documentation](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/md__schemas.html) mentions that the fields are optional in the data.

> Each field is optional: It does not have to appear in the wire
>   representation, and you can choose to omit fields for each individual
>   object.

I am bit confused on how does the flatbuffer differentiates between two similar fields if one of them is not written.

For eg.

```
table Monster {
  hp:short;
  hpNew:short;
}
```

here if I write only `hpNew` in the data file, how will the reader know this is `hpNew` or `hp` ?

Comment: To add to this question, does attribute `id`  play a role in simplifying read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[medium article](https://medium.com/@icex33/beyond-json-introduction-to-flatbuffers-fba1dfd0dcfe) explains that the table in memory is started with a **reference to a virtual table** which tells us where to find the properties.

If there are fields that are not written (optional), this virtual table will have its offset marked as 0.

PS: seems this is the reason tables have higher cost than structs, and also why flatbuffer is better than Cap'n Proto (which doesn't support this).

Comment: I still have doubt that how are we saving in file size when we are writing these 0s for offset in virtual table.  Do we only rely on gain when virtual tables are common?